# I need a comfortable way to work on my server class in ec2 instance

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-ec2

I have an instance of amazon ec2, and I have a java project in it. I'm loging in with putty and I'm looking for a way to update the code I'm writing in that project. For now, I'm writing in eclipse on my computer and transfer the whole project every time I change something. The editor ec2 offers is not a good one to work with. Is there a way to work directly on that project with eclipse or another good editor like notepad++ ?

Comment: rdp, samba, nfs, ftp, rsync, svn, maven - many different ways

Comment: how do I use them? should I install them on the instance or on my computer?

Comment: do some research and find out what they are, see which once fits in with your workflow (or change your workflow), and then see what you need to install.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a version control system, for example git. "Transferring" the files then becomes as simple as `git push` on your development machine and `git pull` on ec2.